# Can't install Android SDK platforms

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Tried to install a couple of Android versions in Android Studio. It tells that installation didn't finish successfully. There such error in the logs: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: packageRoot must exist and be a directory.` 
Java is installed properly.